# angular modal how to change .modal-body padding

Tags: angularjs, padding, bootstrap-modal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SWAU.jpg)CSS:the picture shows that the first css works but the second one not works.

```
.large-Modal .modal-dialog{
  width:800px;
}

.large-Modal .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body {
  padding: 10px!important;
}
```

JS:

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: 'checkDetailModel.html',
    controller: 'checkDetailModalCtrl',
    windowClass: 'large-Modal',
    resolve: {
        epInfoDetail: function () {
            return epInfoDetail;
        }
    }
});
```

How to make `.large-Modal .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body` CSS work?

Comment: Can you show us the rendered html once the modal is shown ?

Comment: Please use developer tool in browser to see whether the css rule is applied first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it like this, and it works fine:

obviously this is in a .css file

```
.app-large-window .modal-dialog {
    width: 900px;
}
```

and `windowClass: 'large'`

Comment: .large-Modal .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body {
  padding: 10px!important;
} this css to change the .modal-body padding not works.